# Issue to send mail?

Tags: java, spring, email

i created the application for mail sending in java Spring, the mail sending properly working in local server. after i export the (war file ) and host into tomcat server then execute the app but mail was not sending i don't know what is the problem of following code?

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("username","password");
                }
            });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("----@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("----@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Test");
            message.setText("Hello"); 
            Transport.send(message); 
            System.out.println("Done"); 
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have to use a valid email address.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: There's nothing here anybody can use to help.

Comment: How are you "executing" in Tomcat?

Comment: Is the port 465 free, not blocked by the **firewall**?

Comment: I got a answer.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer,it's nothing but the port numbers is problem, I'm change and use this two port number 25 (or) 587.